# CPU cap for IIS application pool

Tags: iis-7.5, windows-server-2008, cpu, application-pool

I have been attempting to implement a CPU cap for a specific IIS application pool running on a web server (Win2K8 R2). I have tried using Windows System Resource Manager using several different process matching criteria, but the process never actually gets capped.

### First Attempt

The first process matching criteria I got from [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/managing-performance-settings/using-wsrm-to-manage-iis-7-apppool-cpu-utilization). The actual matching criteria I entered was `@w3wp.exe.*MyAppPoolName`

Then I created my resource allocation policy, and pointed it at the above process matching criteria. I capped the CPU at 25%, enabled the policy, started my app pool, and kicked off the application running in the pool. The app pool's CPU immediately spiked over the 25% limit and stayed there fairly consistently.

### Second Attempt

The next matching criteria I tried came from [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732948.aspx). The actual matching criteria I entered was `@.*w3wp\.exe.*MyAppPoolName.*`

I updated my allocation policy to point to the new matching criteria, and started everything back up. Again, immediately spiked over the limit.

### Third Attempt

On my third and final attempt, I used the built-in controls in the Add Rule dialog in WSRM. I selected IIS App-Pool from the drop-down, clicked the Select... button, then chose my app pool. The matching criteria it generated was `C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe * -ap "MyAppPoolName"`

Again, I updated my allocation policy, and started everything up. Again, immediately spiked over the limit.

---

Has anyone else ever actually been successful at implementing one of these allocation policies? They seem very straightforward to set up, but have been nothing but a pain to actually get to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or update to Windows 2012 with IIS 8 which supports this [out of the box](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-cpu-throttling-sand-boxing-sites-and-applications). IIS 7+ does support CPU monitoring but only offers to kill the application pool if it goes over the limit.